why running my flutter application give an error
Flutter failed to write to a file at "C:\Projects\mini_project.flutter-plugins". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory. Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
I have already check all the access of the project / file and it already has granted all the permission to all the user and also currently i'm operating my pc as an administrator.
I have tried to solve this error via chat gpt but all the actions are done already.

move you flutter sdk to "D" drive

Run flutter doctor to see if everything is correctly configured. Most likely your flutter SDK cannot be found in you PATH
